# Wie sagt man "Sleeping schedule" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Wir müssen Schlafzeitplan der Kinder ändern.

```
 We need to change the children's sleeping schedule.
```

Wie sagt man " sleeping schedule" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Zusammenhang mit Kindern wird häufig folgender Ausdruck benutzt:

> Ab ins Bett Kinder, es ist **Schlafenszeit**!

Dementsprechend könnte man folgende Übersetzung verwenden:

> Wir müssen die Schlafenszeiten der Kinder ändern.

Bei Erwachsenen würde man wohl eher **Schlafrhythmus** verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

Ich höre dafür eigentlich nur ein Wort: "Schlafrhythmus".

> Mein Schlafrhythmus ist in den letzten Tagen ein wenig durcheinander geraten.